# Difference between C# cryptoSha256 and HashLib Sha256

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography

Good morning,
I need to Encryption a file in a Hash mode.

I look this library to use

[HashLibrary](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=hashlib#514361)

My Test with local C# 256 Method and HashLib Method get Differents Results,

```
                FileStream fileStream;
                SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();

                fileStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Open);
                fileStream.Position = 0;

                ///using System.Security.Cryptography;
                byte[] hashValue = sha256.ComputeHash(fileStream);
                string hash = ByteArrayToString(hashValue);

                #region using HashLib;
                //Run Hash
                IHash hash256 = HashFactory.Crypto.CreateSHA256();
                HashResult result256 = hash256.ComputeStream(fileStream);
                byte[] bytearray = result256.GetBytes();
                string stringtest = result256.ToString();
                stringtest = result256.ToString().Replace("-", "");
                #endregion
```

Result of First Method

> byte[] hashValue = 94,171,27,169,32,82,120,2,177,84,58,6,216,77,110,239,85,282,75,159,183,85,70,208,22,146,201,22,47,122,153,74
>
> string hash = 5EAB1BA920527802B1543A06D84D6EEF55FC4B9FB75546D01692C9162F7A994A

Result of Second Method with HashLib

> var bytearray = 227,176,196,66,152,252,28,20,154,251,244,200,153,11,185,36,39,174,65,228,100,155,147,76,164,149,153,27,120,82,184,85
>
> var stringtest = E3B0C442-98FC1C14-9AFBF4C8-996FB924-27AE41E4-649B934C-A495991B-7852B855

Someone can help me? i dont understand what is the problem, why result are differents?.

I start to use this library becouse i cant sha224, sha1 with System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: Why do you convert to hexadecimals differently for both situations? Note that the person that thought to name the method `ByteArrayToString` should be hit on the head with a cluestick - possibly repeatedly. And yes, probably taken from StackOverflow, I know - all the more reason to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have read everything from the stream, so you're at the end of the stream. Recreate it to perform the testing. The second string is the well known hash over an empty array (aka nuthin').

Sometimes it is easy to check your output against well known tools such as `sha256sum`. For instance, the empty array can be tested like this, given a normal *nix shell (e.g. Cygwin or the Windows Subsystem for Linux I suppose):

```
$ dd count=0 status=none | sha256sum -b | awk '{print $1}'
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Comment: Best, this solution for me is succesful, using FileStream fs = new FileStream, I test in both and result is the same. Thanks you a lot